# GoogleDriveAPIv3 - Can I upload binary data in python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have variables which contain binary image data, mime type and file name.
I want to upload the binary data to Google Drive.
Are there any ways to upload this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upload is done in two parts first you upload the metadata, name , description .. then you upload a file stream containing the file data itself

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg', mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

[Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#python)

Comment: Thanks. I want to upload the binary data directly, not save it to a file temporary. Can I do this?

Comment: you are limited to what the [MediaFileUpload](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload-class.html) method supports